# Нет картинки роботов у капчи

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На enSO в диалоге с капчой показывается вот эта картинка:

[image: enSO version]

А на ruSO значок несуществующего изображения.

[image: ruSO версия]

Адрес картинки в разметке:

```
<img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/ru/img/captcha.png" alt="" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
```

---

In English above the "Are you a robot?" check there is this image:

[image: enSO version]

This is what the Russian version looks like:

[image: ruSO версия]

Here is the offending HTML:

```
<img src="//cdn.sstatic.net/ru/img/captcha.png" alt="" style="width: 100%; margin-bottom: 10px;">
```

Comment: Электроника с Сыроежкиным туда )))

Comment: А где это можно воспроизвести?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, при ответе на любой вопрос, но не всегда. Понятия не имею, по какому признаку меня периодически считают роботом. Но в этом году оно воспроизводилось.

Comment: там всё ещё значок несуществующего изображения?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, в этом году я точно видел значок несуществующего изображения. И вообще ни разу не видел там изображения. Точнее сказать не могу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, по-прежнему воспроизводится. Добавил скриншот.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я всё ещё не робот, а картинки всё ещё нет. По крайней мере, вчера.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ау?

Comment: А я-то что? У меня нет прямого выхода на разработчиков )

Comment: Вчера воспроизводилось.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну хотя бы кривенький какой-нибудь :)

Comment: "И мы больше не будем беспокоить вас" - врут) Хоть `reCaptcha` пока доверяет, не заставляет витрины среди дорожных знаков искать)

Comment: О как. Как раз одолела эта напасть в последнее время. Задолбался я витрины выбирать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone set the wrong file extension on the robot image - it was a jpg, not a png.

This is now fixed.

---

Кто-то поставил неверное расширение для картинки робота - это было jpg, а не png.

Сейчас это исправлено.

Comment: Thanks, dude!..